# Accessing nested list items in an interpolated string using dot notation in Scala

Tags: json, scala, string-interpolation

I'm trying to pass a value via JSON that I am having trouble accessing. We have a data structure (that was obviously not built by me otherwise I would likely understand it) that looks something like this when sent to the browser:

`{Foo(Bar(List(Baz(List(G3),w))),G3,None)}`

This is sent via a JSON write method, but the originating Scala line looks like:

`val hint = Some(s"{$question}")` where `$question` is of type `Foo`.

I've tried using dot notation to access the list items in ways that I thought would work:

`val hint = Some(s"{$question.Bar.Baz})"
val hint = Some(s"{$question.Bar(0).Baz(0)"})`

It's the deepest `G3` I wanted to strip out and send, but instead the JSON object comes through looking like:

`{Foo(Bar(List(Baz(List(G3),w))),G3,None)}.Bar.Baz` or
`{Foo(Bar(List(Baz(List(G3),w))),G3,None)}.Bar(0).Baz(0)`

I must be fundamentally missing something about the data structures involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just using the wrong syntax.  The `$` needs to come before the `{}` and the `{}` is necessary for any expression more complicated than just a variable name:

```
 s"${question.bar(0).baz(0)}"
```

Comment: I think you were right about the `$`, but now I'm getting a compilation error that bar is not a member of foo. Looking at the JSON, I thought it was.

It compiled before, so I actually think the fact that this broke it more means we're on the right track.

Comment: So this is essentially correct. The compilation issue is that, in Scala, I'm referencing the classes and should be referencing the property names of Foo which are of type Bar and Baz but have different names as properties of Foo.